# Google Analytics dasboard widget to only show organic traffic coming from search enginges

Tags: google-analytics, widgets

I am now displaying organic traffic in a Google Analytics dashboard widget by filtering `Medium` and `Traffic Type`, and they both are set to `organic`.

What do I set in filters to show just a specific search engines's traffic, like just Google or just Bing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to create a Google Analytics dashboard widget for Google traffic.

- Widget title: Google referrals
- Standard: Timeline
- Graph the following metric over time: Visits
- Filter this data: Only show full referrer containing "google"

[image: Google Analytics dashboard widget for Google traffic]

You can clone this and change "Google" to "Bing" to get a similar widget for bing.